# Mysql Workbench converted tables and columns to lowercase that doesnt work in Linux (AWS -EC2)

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I just moved my Laravel project to aws Elastic Beanstalk, after moving I moved my local databse to aws RDS using Mysql Workbench. All worked fine. But mysql workbench converted all tablenames and column names to lower case. ( I used CamelCase for tables and column in my local mysql and coding). Now since linux is case sensitive its shwoing me tons of errors which says table names dont found etc. It is just because I used camelcase in my codig.

Now its just totally blowing my mind away, I am already late on launching date and this now this issue..ughh. Do I have to change all the tablenames, column names etc in my coding to lower case? That would be totally inefficient and ot would require a lot of time obviously. Is there anyway around to solve this issue? Do I have to use other tool like DBeaver or something? Please help. I just need to upload my mysqlDatabase to aws RDS in same camelCase that I have in local  environment. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

OK So I have found a solution. You dont have to change all the occurrences of tables and column names in your laravel code. You just have to change tableNames to all lowercase in following files.

- controllers
- views (if you used queries to access data in your views)
- models